# Unable to erase data from old Windows XP PC

Tags: windows-xp, format

I have an old Dell PC (326V50J) that I would like all data to be erased from (data and OS). The operating system installed is Windows XP x86. It doesn't have a USB port but it does have a CD drive.

Tasks I did :

- Reinstall OS to remove partitions from disk C: but the machine refused to boot from the CD (it works on another machine).
- Install Lubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-i386 to remove partitions from disk C: (It boots from CD but refuses to install the OS).
- Tried to use the prompt command but it refuses to erase all on C:.
- Low-level formatting (does not work)

Error log:

```
[14.434182] Kernel panic 
[14.434511] panic+0X94/0x1e6
[14.434741] kernel_init_freeable+0x1d0/0x1e2
[14.435045] [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0) ]
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this task is in a corporate environment then there are two useful approaches to this problem. The hard disk should be overwritten in a way that is compliant with your security policies (different firms will have different views as to how unrecoverable your data needs to be). it is not sufficient to simply delete files or quick format a disk as this would leave the data as easily recoverable.

1) set up a workstation with erasure software and a disk caddy to accept a range of old disks. Remove the disk from your PC to erase it. You would want to cover SATA and IDE in both 2.5" and 3.5" formats. You may need two caddies to achieve this. Suitable erasure software would be [Eraser](https://eraser.heidi.ie/) or [sdelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) (there are many others that can run on most operating systems).

2) set up a bootable CD with an automatic whole disk eraser system installed. Put this in the PC and wait for it to erase all drives. An example of this would be [DBAN](https://dban.org), although this may not be available for commercial use. There are many others. There are USB variants on this approach.